# Picking the first and last ranked average

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a result set that has been ranked by an average.

```
LOCATION      JOB TILE    AVG    RANK
SEATTLE      PRESIDENT    10.2    1
SEATTLE         VP        8.5     2
SEATTLE       SN. VP      5.4     3
CHICAGO      SALESMAN     7.6     1
CHICAGO      ENGINEER     3.2     2
CHICAGO      PRESIDENT    1.5     3
```

The next part I need is the is the first and last ranked averages plus the JOB TITLE for each LOCATION group.
Example:

```
LOCATION  JOBTITLE   AVG
SEATTLE   PRESIDENT  10.2
SEATTLE   SN. VP     5.4  
CHICAGO   SALESMAN   7.6
CHICAGO   PRESIDENT  1.5
```

Is there an easy way to do this using just Redshift SQL? Just an FYI, the AVG field is as aggregation done within the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the min and max average for each location and join it to the original query with averages, to get the desired rows.

```
with averages as (<your query>)
,minandmax as (select location, min(avgcol) minavg, max(avgcol) maxavg
               from averages
               group by location)
select a.location,a.job_title, a.avgcol
from averages a
join minandmax m on m.location = a.location and (m.maxavg=a.avgcol or m.minavg=a.avgcol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(rank) over (partition by location) as maxr
      from t
     ) t
where rank in (1, maxr);
```